# Create time-sensitive Firebase (FCM) notifications that disappear after a certain amount of time

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create FCM push notifications that only display for x hours before being automatically cleared.

In particular, the desired behavior is that the server sends a PN and the notification is displayed. x hours after the notification is shown, it disappears on it's own. Ideally, this should happen even if the app is killed. Ideally, it would work on both iOS and Android, but a solution for either system is appreciated.

Is anything like this possible?

I'm using Flutter and Firebase/FCM.